# Background Color for Radiobutton

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

In a MetroWindow I want to create three big rectangular radio buttons. When selected the radio button should change his background color to mark it as selected.

Currently I have somewhat like this:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<ma:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfForm.MainWindow"
    xmlns:ma="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfForm"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="720" Width="1280" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" Background="White" Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.285*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="4,0,3,0"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                SelectionChanged="MainWindowTabControl_SelectionChanged" >
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Aktion" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <RadioButton Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" 
                             Grid.Column="0" 
                             IsChecked="{Binding isFirstButtonSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                             Width="210" Height=" 320" 
                             Margin="0,0,0,170"  
                             BorderBrush="#FF707070" 
                             ma:ButtonHelper.CornerRadius="50" 
                             FontSize="28"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                             ma:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True"
                             Content="Text1">
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" 
                             Grid.Column="1" 
                             IsChecked="{Binding isSecondButtonSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                             Width="210" Height=" 320" 
                             Margin="0,0,0,170"  
                             BorderBrush="#FF707070" 
                             ma:ButtonHelper.CornerRadius="50"
                             FontSize="28"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                             ma:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True"
                             Content="Text2"/>
                <RadioButton Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" 
                             Grid.Column="2" 
                             IsChecked="{Binding isThirdButtonSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                             Width="210" Height=" 320" 
                             Margin="0,0,0,170"  
                             BorderBrush="#FF707070" 
                             ma:ButtonHelper.CornerRadius="50"
                             FontSize="28"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                             ma:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True"
                             Content="Text3">
                </RadioButton>
                <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="35,3"
                        Margin="0,0,8,6" Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="{Binding ActionTabAllowNext, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Command="{Binding ActionCommand}" Content="Next" FontSize="18" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</ma:MetroWindow>
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfForm.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfForm"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Crimson.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

When clicking on the button it only changes color on hovering and on mouse press but changes back to normal on mouse release. Maybe I can add an additional property to mark the buttons as selected?

**Solution**

The answer below worked for me. Thank you for your help.
In the end I made another approach that fits better: I changed the style for the RadioButtons to a ToggleButton. Nevertheless the answer below  is correct.

Comment: If you want help debugging your code, then you should post it so people can copy it and try to reproduce your problem. If you want someone to write the code for you, you should try a different Web site.

Comment: @Abra Sorry. I don't want someone to write the code for me. I am only searching for a way to change the background (maybe with `backgroundWhenSelected`). I will add the full code, if that is better for you

Comment: Friend, can you post the code part that defines your "SquareButtonStyle"? If you dont find it, right click on "SquareButtonStyle" and click "Go to Definition" then copy and paste that style definition here. @BigSilence

Comment: @csstudent1418 Hey, I don't have access to the definition. Above I have added the way mahapps.metro is included into my project. By changing the Style to, for example AccentedSquareButtonStyle, I use another predefined Style. For that I also can't navigate to the definition. Unfortunately the [website](https://mahapps.com/) also doesn't show anything about that.

Comment: @BigSilence did you try my answer?

Comment: @csstudent1418 Sorry  for my absence. I tried it and it works but not as I was expecting. I changed the style to ToggleButton to achieve my needs.

Comment: @BigSilence No worries. May I ask if you don't mind, what did not work as you expected exactly? I'm curious if I could still help you further because I believe it should work the way I'm imagining it, as I have done quite a bit of styling in XAML just like this. Cheers!

Comment: @csstudent1418 The main reason is, that there are too many options I can change and those I have to change to get the desired look. By simply typing a one liner I got what I needed. So your answer is correct and maybe I use it in other scenarios but in this one I go with the ToggleButtons predefined style. 
Things I would have to edit are color, hover behavior, selected color, unselected color and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the style definition online on mahapp's github: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.RadioButton.xaml

Just copy and paste it into your App.xaml for example and change the color values as you wish.

Don't forget to rebind the style to your edited version wherever you use a RadioButton.